# Adding a whitelist to a python socket server

Tags: python, sockets

I am wondering how I would make a whitelist, or a list of allowed IPs. There is someone trying to join my server, and he uses a VPN to hide his IP and change it. Please help me, it’s shutting down my server every time he does this.

My code is:

```
import socket
import threading


class ChatServer:
    clients_list = []

    last_received_message = ""

    def __init__(self):
        self.server_socket = None
        self.create_listening_server()

    def create_listening_server(self):
        self.server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        local_ip = '127.0.0.1'
        local_port = 10319
        # this will allow you to immediately restart a TCP server
        self.server_socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
        # this makes the server listen to requests coming from other computers on the network
        self.server_socket.bind((local_ip, local_port))
        print("Listening for incoming messages..")
        self.server_socket.listen(5)
        self.receive_messages_in_a_new_thread()

    def receive_messages(self, so):
        while True:
            incoming_buffer = so.recv(256)
            if not incoming_buffer:
                break
            self.last_received_message = incoming_buffer.decode('utf-8')
            self.broadcast_to_all_clients(so)  # send to all clients
        so.close()

    def broadcast_to_all_clients(self, senders_socket):
        for client in self.clients_list:
            socket, (ip, port) = client
            if socket is not senders_socket:
                socket.sendall(self.last_received_message.encode('utf-8'))

    def receive_messages_in_a_new_thread(self):
        while True:
            client = so, (ip, port) = self.server_socket.accept()
            self.add_to_clients_list(client)
            print('Connected to ', ip, ':', str(port))
            t = threading.Thread(target=self.receive_messages, args=(so,))
            t.start()

    def add_to_clients_list(self, client):
        if client not in self.clients_list:
            self.clients_list.append(client)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    ChatServer()
```

In `receive_messages_in_a_new_thread(self)`, I am getting an IP of the client. I tried using:

```
whitelist = [“client-ip”, “client-ip”]
if ip not in whitelist:
    so.close()
else:
    pass
```

But it still lets other IPs in. I even tried a blacklist:

```
blacklist = [“client-ip”, “client-ip”]
if ip in blacklist:
    so.close()
else:
    pass
```

What am I missing? Is there another thing that I should know about?

Comment: I have a suggestion, instead of trying to blacklist or whitelist IPs, you can try doing either method with MAC addresses since they are permanent on the system. I don't know how to do it but i found an article that might help you, [check this out](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/extracting-mac-address-using-python/)

Comment: How do I block the MAC address? It seems if statements don’t work.

Comment: I'm not so sure how this would go but I think it's like this: Make a blacklist of MAC addresses and loop through that list. Then check the MAC address for each connected client. If the address matches one in the blacklist, close their connection.

Comment: Ok, I looked up MAC addresses and I can’t find anything about getting one from a client

Comment: I looked at the article, it shows how to get **my** MAC address, not from a client

Comment: Oh sorry, I'm multitasking here, didn't really read the article verbaitm. Here's another method. If you have nmap installed, try `sudo nmap -sn <server ip>/24`. Note that you **must** be using `sudo` or you **must be root** to see MAC addresses. Also don't forget that `/24` after the ip address. With `subprocess`, you can execute this command but it's a little ugly, as far as formatting goes. You might want to make use of the `re` library or others like those

Comment: did my suggestion help you?

Comment: You typically only see MAC addresses for devices directly connected to your network. For someone coming in from the internet their MAC address will appear to be your router.

Comment: @MatthewSchell, the command didn’t work and I didn’t understand where I would get the address.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk, Oh, okay. I’m using bind() now to limit the amount of connections.

Comment: @CharonProgramer, did you run the command in the terminal before using subprocess on it? If you were using subprocess, you would need to capture output and print that out to see the results.

Comment: I ran it in the terminal, it didn’t work

Comment: I found a new way, my code originally was incorrect. Sorry for wasting your time.